# Redundant proof in Math paper

Tags: soft-question

Recently, I read a published math paper and I found that in the excessive argument in the proof of one of its theorem. In fact, in my opinion, the redundant part is not even correct, because it applies a theorem in wrong manner. 
However, the flaw can not be detected trivially.

My questions:

1. Is it normal if the detail of some published math paper contains flaw and redundant argument like this?
2. Why did the referee and/or editor approve the publication of the paper without correction?
3. As a beginner (undergraduate student), how does one improve the ability to read math paper critically without sacrificing the reader's time?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I suspect that if you read carefully and have a sufficiently deep understanding then you can find plenty of stuff in papers that is either wrong or could be simplified considerably.  You'll even find occasional errors in textbooks.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:undergraduate-research] tag. It is being removed.

Comment: This seems more of an editorial comment about "published math papers" and your personal ability to critique them.  The "questions" you list ("Is it normal...", "Why did the referee and/or editor...", etc.) are not amenable to reasoned mathematical argument given the complete lack of particulars about the paper and the journal where you found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not rare for math papers to have minor issues. Referees do the best job they can, but their job is not to find every minor issue - the author should ideally do that. Papers are written by humans, in any case, so perfection is rarely achieved.

This doesn't have as much impact as you might think because people don't blindly cite proofs from other papers.  If a paper proves an important result, which others are planning to rely on, the others will check the proof to their own satisfaction.  Refereeing does catch many errors, but nobody relies on refereeing alone for important results.

Another reason that minor errors might be overlooked is that, apart from perhaps the referee, working mathematicians who read a proof often read it just to get the main idea, and then re-work the proof in their own head, rather than following along with the author's description of the proof. For experienced mathematicians, that's often more efficient than trying to work out the details of what the author is saying. Only when the mathematicans can't work out the proof on their own do they need to try to decipher the author's detailed argument.

That's very different from how students (undergraduate and graduate) read papers. Students often have less experience with the "standard" techniques, and need more than just a hint about how to prove a theorem. So students often need to read the full proofs. When doing so, take note of which ones you think are clear, and which you think are not, and try to emulate the clear ones in your own writing.

Answer (score 3):

For questions 1 and 2, it is impossible to answer in a sensible way without knowing what paper you are talking about.

For question 3, just read more papers. After a while you'll get faster and better at discerning what parts and results of a paper interest you, and what is irrelevant for your research and therefore skippable.